# Dynamic algorithm for minimum weight of a dominating set in a partial k-tree

Tags: graph, tree, dynamic-programming

Let G be a graph with vertex-weights w : V → R<sup>+</sup>. A dominating set is a set D of
vertices in G such that all vertices of G are either in D , or have a neighbor in D. The minimum-weight dominating set is the dominating set D that has the minimum possible weight w(D) = ∑<sub>v∈D</sub> w(v). Now i'm seeking a **dycnamic programming algorithm** to find the minimum weight of a dominating set in a **partial k-tree**(not tree).